# Why won't mocha recognise my error?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have the following test case in Mocha..

```
.toThrowError("invalid")
```

However despite the below code (the code in the if block executes correctly)

```
   try {
    let arr = [];
    existing.forEach((exists) => {
        arr.push(...this.dependencies[exists]);
    });
    for (let x in arr){
        if(existing.indexOf(arr[x]) == -1){
            throw new Error('invalid');
        }
    }
  }

  catch(e){
     console.log(e); 
  }
```

I get the following message. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Expected the function to throw an error matching:
  "Invalid Base Permissions"
But it didn't throw anything.
```

Comment: The exception is never thrown. Are you sure there is supposed to be an exception? Seems to me the `if` statement is never true. You can test that by putting a `!` before the `existing.indexOf` and checking if that triggers the exception.

Comment: Can you include the following test case, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've caught the error yourself, so as far as mocha is concerned, it didn't throw an error (the error is handled before it gets to the test). If you don't rely on the error being caught in your code, remove the try-catch and it should (assuming the error is actually thrown) work.